# Where does CakePHP store model instances?

Tags: cakephp

Where does CakePHP store model instances, or how can I get a list of all the models that have been loaded already?

I know about

```
App::objects('model');
```

But that just lists all the available models ...

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassRegistry` holds the loaded model instances. So [ClassRegistry::keys()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-ClassRegistry.html#_keys) is what you are looking for.